# Symfony problem with jq_link_to_remote

Tags: symfony1, link-to-remote

Hy,

I'm using jq_link_to_remote function to load in a div a form to do answers to a comment (like in facebook). My problem is that i call this form like that 'social/respond/id/14'  where id content the parent opinion. I create a funcion that setValue to a hidden field in my form.

Then, why if i try to call directly 'social/respond/id/14' it assign correctly value and when i do it with jq_link call not? I do a 'echo' of value passed as input in function than set value of field and it works fine.

Thanks.

**Form code..**

```
public function setDefaultEntityId($id_response=0)
  {
   if($id_response!=0){
     $this->setDefault('sf_opinion_id',$id_response);   
   }
   $this->configure();
  }
```

**template opinions**

```
<?php echo jq_link_to_remote('opinar', 
                 array(
                        'update' => 'respuesta_hidden_'.$opinion->getId(), 
                         'url'  => 'social/responder?id_response='.$opinion->getId()),array('rel' => 'nofollow','class' =>'mini')
```

); ?>

**action responder**

```
$this->form = new OpinionResForm();

$this->form->setDefaultEntityId($request->getParameter('id_response'));

// formulario opiniones
if($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST))
{
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
    if ($this->form->isValid()) {
    $opinion = $this->form->save();  
    }
}
```

And finally, an example of generated code...

```
<a onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',dataType:'html',success:function(data, textStatus){jQuery('#respuesta_hidden_1').html(data);},url:'/sfproject/zampalo/web/frontend_dev.php/social/responder/id_response/1'}); return false;" href="#" class="mini" rel="nofollow">opinar</a>
```

I hope that helps... :)

Comment: AJAX problems are tricky to debug without some code examples - can you provide the code for the targeted symfony action, `jq_link_to_remote` snippet, and the resulting HTML from the `jq_link_to_remote` function?

Comment: added more information ;)
thanks Raise

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it looks clean - I'm not sure what the problem is. However, I'm not sure why you do this in the form:

```
if($id!=0){
  $this->setDefault('id_elemento',$id);
}
if($id_response!=0){
  $this->setDefault('id_elemento',$id_response); 
}
```

you are setting the default for id_elemento twice - if $id and $id_response are not 0, then id_elemento gets set to $id first, then $id_response... which doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'll try it later but it seems that is the problem... :(
Thank you so much Raise!

Comment: I edited information. Still not working :(
If i run... social/responder/id_response/1  directly it works, via jquery not :(

Comment: Raise... any idea? How can I test it or know what are failing?

Comment: At this point, no. My only recommendation is to install the Tamper Data plugin for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/966 and use it to inspect your AJAX transactions by monitoring the request/responses via the Tamper Data window. You should be able to see what variables are not being set.